# Sendmail says it has sent, but doesn't actually send

Tags: debian, sendmail, smtp

I installed sendmail using this tutorial:

[Install sendmail debian gnu linux](http://pc-freak.net/blog/install-sendmail-debian-gnu-linux/)

I am using this command to send my test email:

```
mail -s "Subject" "xxxxxxxx@outlook.com" <<< "This is the body"
```

`mail.log` in `/var/log` says:

```
Dec 29 18:15:28 raspberrypi sendmail[14546]: tBU2FSim014546: from=root, size=232, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201512300215.tBU2FSim014546@raspberrypi.home>, relay=root@localhost
Dec 29 18:15:28 raspberrypi sm-mta[14547]: tBU2FS3h014547: from=<root@raspberrypi.home>, size=480, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201512300215.tBU2FSim014546@raspberrypi.home>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Dec 29 18:15:28 raspberrypi sendmail[14546]: tBU2FSim014546: to=xxxxxxx@outlook.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30232, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (tBU2FS3h014547 Message accepted for delivery)
```

Despite what the log says about the message being accepted, I never get the message. Does anyone know what is going on? I didn't know what to include in my question, so if you need more info, just ask. Thank you!

I am using Debian Jessie.

Comment: Does your provider block outbound port 25?

Comment: It is my server, so no.

Comment: That has nothing to do with whether your provider blocks port 25. By provider I mean ISP.

Comment: I don't think so. How would I find out?

Comment: Try with a `-v` flag added to `mail`, it tend to give much more useful info for  you and anyone trying to assist...

The destination server might also be sending the mail directly to spam... (This can be reduced with black magic, reverse DNS matching forward DNS and other types of config changes...)

Comment: Have you posted **ALL** log entries with `tBU2FS3h014547`?

Comment: per @AndrzejA.Filip's comment, your last "accepted" line was to localhost; where did it go from there?

Comment: I don't know, that's all it gave me

Answer (score 1):

### Sendmail: sending a test message

**As root** execute shell script below to send a test message with SMTP session tracking.  It usually provides some helpful clues.

```
#!/bin/sh
RECIPIENT="xxxxxxxx@outlook.com"

/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -v -Am -- $RECIPIENT <<END
Subject: test message
To: $RECIPIENT

This is a test messsage
END
```